Gridview padding changes based on target
I'm working on a Flutter project where I have a PageView with three children. Each child contains a LayoutBuilder that builds a GridView.
When I don't specify any padding, the grid looks like this:

However, when I add padding directly to the GridView or wrap it with padding, everything looks correct on a desktop screen, but on mobile devices, there’s extra padding or space at the bottom of the grid.
Desktop View (Correct): The layout appears as expected, with consistent padding around the grid.
Mobile View (Incorrect): On mobile devices (and Raspberry Pi using Flutter-pi), the same grid has extra space below the last row, even though no additional padding is set there.
Question:
Why does the layout behave differently on mobile devices compared to desktop, and how can I ensure a consistent UI across all platforms, including when embedded on a Raspberry Pi using Flutter-pi?


class MainPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
          vertical: 50.0,
        ),
        child: PageView(
          controller: PageController(
            initialPage: 0,
            viewportFraction: 0.9,
          ),
          children: const [
            GrindBuilderBeverages(
              backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent,
              rows: 4,
              columns: 4,
              crossAxisSpacing: 15.0,
              mainAxisSpacing: 20.0,
            ),
            GrindBuilderBeverages(
              backgroundColor: Colors.purpleAccent,
              rows: 3,
              columns: 3,
              crossAxisSpacing: 10.0,
              mainAxisSpacing: 10.0,
            ),
            GrindBuilderBeverages(
              backgroundColor: Colors.greenAccent,
              rows: 2,
              columns: 5,
              crossAxisSpacing: 5.0,
              mainAxisSpacing: 5.0,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class GrindBuilderBeverages extends StatelessWidget {
  final Color backgroundColor;
  final int rows;
  final int columns;
  final double crossAxisSpacing;
  final double mainAxisSpacing;

  const GrindBuilderBeverages(
      {super.key,
      required this.backgroundColor,
      required this.rows,
      required this.columns,
      required this.crossAxisSpacing,
      required this.mainAxisSpacing});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: backgroundColor,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16.0),
      ),
      child: LayoutBuilder(
        builder: (context, constraints) {
          // Calculate the childAspectRatio based on the available width and height
          final double totalHorizontalSpacing = (columns - 1) * crossAxisSpacing;
          final double totalVerticalSpacing = (rows - 1) * mainAxisSpacing;

          final double itemWidth =
              (constraints.maxWidth - totalHorizontalSpacing) / columns;
          final double itemHeight =
              (constraints.maxHeight - totalVerticalSpacing) / rows;
          final double aspectRatio = itemWidth / itemHeight;

          return GridView.builder(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
            gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
              crossAxisCount: columns, // Set the number of columns
              childAspectRatio: aspectRatio, // Dynamic aspect ratio
              crossAxisSpacing: crossAxisSpacing, // Horizontal spacing
              mainAxisSpacing: mainAxisSpacing, // Vertical spacing
            ),
            itemCount: rows * columns, // Total number of items
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return Container(
                color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.5),
                child: Center(
                  child: Text(
                    'Item $index',
                    style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}


A simple solution would be to change the code according to the platform, you can do such a thing by using the 'dart:io' library.
here is an example:
import'dart:io' show Platform;
void main(){
   if(Platform.isIOS){
     //make the Grid for the IOS
   }else if(Platform.isAndroid){
     //make the Grid for the Android
   }else if (Platform.isWindows) {
     // make the Grid for the Windows
   }else if(Platform.isMacOS){
     //make the Grid for the MacOS
}

And you can explore more and learn how to use it from the Flutter documentation for sure: https://flutter.dev/
